# Why does Devel::REPL ignore my --rcfile?

Tags: perl, read-eval-print-loop

Use case:

```
$ cat test.rc 
my $a = 'foo';
$ re.pl --rcfile test.rc
$ $a                                                                                                                                      
$
```

Expected output: `foo`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, the path handling is a bit funny:

```
$ re.pl --rcfile ./test.rc                                                                                            
$ $a                                                                                                                                      
foo
```

It’s in the documentation:

> To set a new run control file that's also in that directory [`$HOME/.re.pl/`], pass it
>   as a filename like so: (…) If the filename happens to contain a
>   forward slash, then it's used absolutely, or realive to the current
>   working directory.